# How to convert string to date time (Non English) in Delphi

Tags: delphi

I am unable to convert my string format date (French) to `TDateTime` format. I am working on files which contain string format dates in English and other languages.

For example, 1st March 2021 will be in an English file as `1 mar 2021`, and in a French file as `1 mars 2021`.

```pascal
var
   _StrDate: String;
   _MyDateTime: TDateTime;
begin
   _StrDate := '1 mar 2021'; // English
   _MyDateTime := VarToDateTime(_StrDate); // works perfect

   _StrDate := '1 mars 2021'; // French
   _MyDateTime := VarToDateTime(_StrDate); // error
end;
```

I'm getting this error msg:

> Could not convert variant of type (UnicodeString) into type (Date)

Comment: Write a parser for your specific format.

Comment: Perhaps it helps to compile your program with library language set to French.

Comment: Welcome to date and time format hell. I'm afraid you will have to write your own parser for that. As far as I know there is none that can understand all or even many of these formats, in particular since they are ambiguous. Do you at least know which format is used for each of the strings so you don't need to guess?

Comment: If you don't know the date formats in the file, and even more so if each file can contain different formats, they you are out of luck. It is impossible to decode the dates. For instance, "20/06/21" could be 2020-06-21 last year or 2021-06-20 this year. Worse, "20/06/05" could be 2020-06-05 last year, 2005-06-20 some 16 years ago, 2020-05-06 last year, or 2006-05-20 some 15 years ago.

Comment: Did you try to set the default formatsettings to use ‘French’: `FormatSettings := TFormatSettings.Create(1036);`.

Comment: @R.Hoek: You should never set the global `FormatSettings` variable. (What if two parts of the code does this? What if they run in parallel?) But you can use the overloads that accept format settings. But that will not work because `StrToDate` simply doesn't support non-numeric months.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand I mend setting it to test whether is works (but as you state, it seems it won’t). However, regarding setting the global `FormatSettings`, my idea was to set it a application startup only (not change it) when french is the only supported locale of the app. However, when it’s not, then your suggestion of using the overloads would be my idea to. But from your comment I see this won’t work too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote a parser for the specific format your have. Well, I have done the basic work, you'll have to modify it for example to use both French and English month names as well as short names. You should also add some tests to filter invalid values out. And probably ignore character casing in the name of months.

```
const
    MonthsFR : array [1..12] of String = (
        'janvier', 'février', 'mars', 'avril', 'mai', 'juin', 'juillet',
        'août', 'septembre', 'octobre', 'novembre', 'décembre');

function StrToDateFR(const S : String; out ADate : TDateTime) : Boolean;
var
    A : TStringDynArray;
    D : Word;
    M : Word;
    Y : Word;
begin
    ADate  := 0;
    Result := FALSE;
    A := SplitString(S, ' ');
    if Length(A) <> 3 then
        Exit;
    D := StrToInt(A[0]);
    M := High(MonthsFR);
    while (M > Low(MonthsFR)) and (A[1] <> MonthsFR[M]) do
        Dec(M);
    if M < Low(MonthsFR) then
        Exit;
    Y := StrToInt(A[2]);

    ADate  := EncodeDate(Y, M, D);
    Result := TRUE;
end;
```

One idea to expand the code is to have several similar functions for other languages. Since the function return TRUE only when the format is recognized, you may call various versions in sequence until one return true.

Comment: Your answer is usefull, , I modified

Answer (score 0):

```
function StrToDateFR(const S: String; out ADate: TDateTime): Boolean;
var

  A: TStringDynArray;
  D: Word;
  M: Word;
  Y: Word;
  i: integer;

begin

  ADate := 0;
  Result := FALSE;
 A := SplitString(S, ' ');
 if Length(A) <> 3 then
    Exit;
  D := StrToInt(A[0]);
  M := 0;

  for i := Low(MonthsFR) to High(MonthsFR) do
  begin
    if SameText(A[1], MonthsFR[i]) then
    begin
      M := i;
      Break
    end;
  end;

  if M = 0 then
    Exit;
  Y := StrToInt(A[2]);

 ADate := EncodeDate(Y, M, D);
 Result := TRUE;

end;
```

Comment: You copied my answer, replacing a while loop by a for-loop. You should remove your answer to your own question and mark MY answer as accepted.

Comment: Your answer accepted, But the difference is when we pass the value '10 avril 2021' the return will be  10/12/2021. But in the modified part  M := i; will give the month part, so the answer will be10/04/2021. Thank you

Comment: There one "not" left in the while condition. Removed now. Thanks.